# What are the specific names for clauses following a comma, dash and such punctuation marks?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, clauses

Do the clauses which follow a dash, colon, open bracket, and such punctuation marks have **specific names** other than just being a clause?

Examples of what I mean with the "***C***"s representing the clauses in question:

1. xxxxxx - ***CCCCCC*** - xxxxxxx.
2. xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx - ***CCCCCC***.
3. xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx: ***CCCCCC***.
4. xxxxxxxx (***CCCCCC***) xxxxxxx.

Are they all just called clauses? Or does each example have specific name to indicate that they follow a certain punctuation mark?

Comment: You need to provide real examples but "The em dash (—) sets off a word or clause and adds emphasis". Don't confuse punctuation marks with what is inside them.

Comment: There are no specific names for types of clause based on punctuation. Clauses are grammatical and grammar refers to spoken language. [Punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf) occurs only in writing, which is technological and not grammatical. Plus, everybody uses punctuation their own way, and everybody thinks their own way is the official way. When, in fact, there is no official way.

Comment: Hi @Lambie, thanks for your comment! I understand the function of these punctuation marks, that's why I didn't put real examples. I just wanted to know if parts of a sentence that follow the punctuation marks (no matter what the sentence says) can be identified with a specific name.

Comment: Hi @John Lawler! I understand, thank you for commenting! I noticed that there were names for very specific uses of the English language (e.g. appositions and scare quotations); so I thought there was a good chance that parts of the sentence that follow a punctuation mark (-, :, etc.) would also have a specific name. I still believe there are "official" ways, but that language is organic and constantly evolving, otherwise there wouldn't millions of hits on Google about grammar and written English.

Comment: Believe us, there is no name for this. Now, what you can put between brackets or em dashes after a colon do have names: clauses or nouns.